# How to convert a byte array to a List<int> in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I am trying to reverse engineer some old data. The database holds a base64 string that represents a List of type int object in C#. That of course can be easily converted to a byte array, but that is where I am stuck. What would I use to convert that byte[] data to the List?

UPDATE: Found the code that converts the bytes to list:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ToCollection(byte[] bitfield)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < bitfield.Length; ix++)
    {
        var i = ix << 3;
        var b = bitfield[ix];
        if ((b & 0x01) != 0) { yield return i + 0; }
        if ((b & 0x02) != 0) { yield return i + 1; }
        if ((b & 0x04) != 0) { yield return i + 2; }
        if ((b & 0x08) != 0) { yield return i + 3; }
        if ((b & 0x10) != 0) { yield return i + 4; }
        if ((b & 0x20) != 0) { yield return i + 5; }
        if ((b & 0x40) != 0) { yield return i + 6; }
        if ((b & 0x80) != 0) { yield return i + 7; }
     }
}
```

New question: how do I reverse this and send a list through this to a byte array?

Comment: Could you provide an example, please? The initial string and the desired list.

Comment: Do you know how the list was originally converted to a byte array before it was encoded to Base64?

Comment: No, that's the mystery.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say the List was serialized with binaryformatter and than stored as base64. try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xByHN9

Comment: though it could be anything - xml, json, yaml and so on - heck it could be a custom string `1|2|3`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the ints are placed contigiously in this byte array, you can use [BitConverter.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-8.0) to convert each int in sequence.

Using a for-loop:

```
ReadOnlySpan<byte> byteArray = ... // your code goes here.
List<int> integers = new();
for (int i = 0; i <= byteArray.Length - 4; i += 4) {
    integers.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray.Slice(i, 4)));
}
```

I haven't tested the code above, but you can adapt it for your own personal solution. Take note, that BitConverter uses the same endianness of your system by default, so you might want to change it if you're expecting a different endianness.

Comment: Also, if you're working with a big database, it might be worth it to consider casting directly to an int array using [Unsafe.As](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.as?view=net-8.0) or something similar. This could potentially have better performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This returned a list with one number instead of a list of different numbers. Incidentally we are only trying to convert a few values so no need to worry about performance or database size thanks.